# Powershell, Get access rights of shared files, format output?

Tags: powershell

I have some shared files set up for me for testing purposes, on a Windows Server 2016.
My given task is to get all the users, and their access rights to there shared files/folders.

I get the shared files with

```
Get-SmbShare | Select-Object -Property Name, Path
```

What I think I should do, is passing each share's path into

```
    Get-Acl
```

So I came up with this:

```
$shares = Get-SmbShare | Where-Object Name -notlike "*$" | Select-Object Name

foreach ($share in $shares){
   $path = "\\$env:COMPUTERNAME\" + $share.Name.ToString()
   $FolderPath = dir -Directory -Path $path -Recurse -Force
   Foreach ($Folder in $FolderPath) {
      $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
      foreach ($Access in $acl.Access)
      {     
            $Folder.FullName;
            $Access.IdentityReference;
            $Access.FileSystemRights;
            $Access.IsInherited
      }
   }
}
```

My question is: How could I format this output, so it looks readable, and/or is there a simpler, maybe cleaner to do what I intend to do?

Comment: As far as the output format, it might help to define what would be more readable, simpler, etc.

Comment: Would outputting as `[PsCustomObject]` be more readable to you? It also has the advantage that this will be easy to export to Csv file if you capture the results from the foreach loop.

Comment: I want to make the separate datas to appear in separate columns.